# Why this "cartesian" method for deriving the expression of curl in cylindrical coordinates fails?

Tags: vector-analysis, curl

I know a lot of alternative methods to the one I describe below, so please **DO NOT** mention any methods other than the one I have below.

We have an expression for $\nabla\times \mathbf A$ in Cartesian coordinates
$$
\left(\frac{\partial A_z}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial A_y}{\partial z}\right) \hat{\mathbf x} \\
+ \left(\frac{\partial A_x}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial A_z}{\partial x}\right) \hat{\mathbf y} \\
+ \left(\frac{\partial A_y}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial A_x}{\partial y}\right) \hat{\mathbf z}.
$$

I believe I can obtain the formula in cylindrical coordinates, starting from the one above. Here is my plan for computing component $\hat{\boldsymbol\varphi}$:

1. Note that $\hat{\boldsymbol\varphi}=-\sin\phi\hat{\mathbf x}+\cos\phi \hat{\mathbf y}$, so to find the $\hat{\boldsymbol\varphi}$ component we just need to evaluate the dot product $$-\sin\phi\left(\frac{\partial A_z}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial A_y}{\partial z}\right) +\cos\phi \left(\frac{\partial A_x}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial A_z}{\partial x}\right)  $$
2. Next, try to change $A_x,A_y$ to $A_\phi,A_r$.

In the second step, I feel things going seriously wrong. I get
$$
\frac{\partial A_y}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial (A_r\sin A_\phi)}{\partial z}=\sin A_\phi\frac{\partial A_r}{\partial z}+\cos A_\phi\frac{\partial A_\phi}{\partial z} A_r.
$$
This is terrible. I am not expecting to see anything like $\sin A_\phi$ in my final answer, and there is no way I can get rid of it or cancel it out.

**What's wrong?**

Comment: Good question! What is wrong is that $A_y$ is not $A_r\sin A_\phi$, it is $A_r \sin\phi + A_\phi\cos\phi$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_fields_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates